# sending simple messages over tcp port

Tags: kotlin, tcp

I would really like to send a very simple message by tcp, with two kotlin programs (server and client) communicating with each other, sending short strings to each other.

I have this very simple code for the server:

```kotlin
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val server = ServerSocket(5000)
    println("Server is running on port ${server.localPort}")

    val socket = server.accept()

    print("connected to client: "+ socket.inetAddress.toString())   
    val text = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.inputStream)).readLine()
}
```

and this for the client:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val socket = Socket("localhost", 5000)

    PrintWriter(socket.outputStream, true).write("text")
}
```

The idea is that i first run the server and then the client, and then send some message from the client to the server (and maybe the other way around). The current thing I have now I tried to grab from this tutorial (https://sylhare.github.io/2020/04/07/Kotlin-tcp-socket-example.html) but simply find it too hard to figure out what to do

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is the TCP stream supposed to consist of lines? You seem to be reading lines but writing formated representations of objects. Your sending code and your receiving code have to agree on the form of data used over the connection or they won't be compatible with each other. Is it lines? Strings? Encoded objects? Or what?

Comment: at the moment anything will do

Comment: Why not just use KTor (https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html) for this?

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you can do:

###### Server

```kotlin
fun server() {
    val server = ServerSocket(9999)
    val client = server.accept()
    val output = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
    val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.inputStream))

    output.println("${input.readLine()} back")
}
```

###### Client

```kotlin
fun client() {
    val client = Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999)
    val output = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
    val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.inputStream))

    println("Client sending [Hello]")
    output.println("Hello")
    println("Client receiving [${input.readLine()}]")
    client.close()
}
```

###### Run together

To run both at the same time:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Thread{ server() }.start()
    client()
}
```

The client will run send a message to the server then receive a response and the program will end.